# nginx docker angular 5 mean setup for https

Tags: docker, nginx, https

I have 4 containers using Docker: client/server/mongo/nginx,  on one of my components I have a button which calls v2.steemconnect.com/api/broadcast:1 POST https://v2.steemconnect.com/api/broadcast

which gives me an error in the browser console 500. I was wondering what is wrong with my nginx conf. everything works if take the server out that listens to 443 https. but then my button doesn't work. 
When I add the server in the nginx conf the normal routing to the client doesn't seem to work anymore over port 80

```html
worker_processes 2 ;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
    upstream my-server {
    server myserver:3000;
    }

    upstream client {
    server client:4200;
    }

    server {
        
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://client;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        }
        location /api/ {
            proxy_pass http://my-server;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }        
    }
    server {

    listen 443;
    

    ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/cert.key;

    ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

   
    location / {

      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      # Fix the “It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
      proxy_pass          http://client;
      proxy_read_timeout  90;
      
    }
  }
}
```

```html
172.18.0.1 - - [11/Jan/2018:16:57:43 +0000] "GET /sockjs-node/info?t=1515689863833 HTTP/1.1" 200 90 "http://localhost/main/(aux:crypto/5a32e59d25b5d2292cc2e919/(blogoutlet:steemblog;access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJyb2xlIjoiYXBwIiwicHJveHkiOiJjcnlwdG9vd2xzLmFwcCIsInVzZXIiOiJvdWRla2FhcyIsInNjb3BlIjpbInZvdGUiLCJjb21tZW50Il0sImlhdCI6MTUxNTY4OTg2MCwiZXhwIjoxNTE2Mjk0NjYwfQ.9WjEtZx1vF0a1dr5X376rw9SeeiRzcjXjw_9l5-APX0;expires_in=604800;userName=oudekaas))" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36"
172.18.0.1 - - [11/Jan/2018:16:57:43 +0000] "GET /api/findPostData HTTP/1.1" 404 155 "http://localhost/main/(aux:crypto/5a32e59d25b5d2292cc2e919/(blogoutlet:steemblog;access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJyb2xlIjoiYXBwIiwicHJveHkiOiJjcnlwdG9vd2xzLmFwcCIsInVzZXIiOiJvdWRla2FhcyIsInNjb3BlIjpbInZvdGUiLCJjb21tZW50Il0sImlhdCI6MTUxNTY4OTg2MCwiZXhwIjoxNTE2Mjk0NjYwfQ.9WjEtZx1vF0a1dr5X376rw9SeeiRzcjXjw_9l5-APX0;expires_in=604800;userName=oudekaas))" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36"
172.18.0.1 - - [11/Jan/2018:16:57:43 +0000] "GET /sockjs-node/236/2jgxtsmj/websocket HTTP/1.1" 400 40 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36"
172.18.0.1 - - [11/Jan/2018:16:57:54 +0000] "POST /api/updatePost?permlink=bitcoin-review-oudekaas HTTP/1.1" 404 154 "http://localhost/main/(aux:crypto/5a32e59d25b5d2292cc2e919/(blogoutlet:steemblog;access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJyb2xlIjoiYXBwIiwicHJveHkiOiJjcnlwdG9vd2xzLmFwcCIsInVzZXIiOiJvdWRla2FhcyIsInNjb3BlIjpbInZvdGUiLCJjb21tZW50Il0sImlhdCI6MTUxNTY4OTg2MCwiZXhwIjoxNTE2Mjk0NjYwfQ.9WjEtZx1vF0a1dr5X376rw9SeeiRzcjXjw_9l5-APX0;expires_in=604800;userName=oudekaas))" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: why are you using upgrade headers? Are you using socket.io?

Comment: I got some failure messages when taking out the Upgrade , not using socket.io. I am struggling to understand if I actually need to setup a https server, I am basically trying to access a third party api that is called through HTTPS rather then HTTP. I will try again without the upgrade. I thought nginx uses websockets for the http:80 calls

Comment: when I delete the cache bypass/ set header Upgrade and proxy set header Connection I am getting a bad gateway error.502

Comment: I am using Docker is websockets required for Docker?

Comment: Can you post the error shown in nginx logs?